# Storing file data variables in a dimentional array

Tags: c++, variables, multidimensional-array

I have a .txt file which I'm trying to gather data from, that can then be used within variables within my code to be used in other functions.

Here's an example of my text file:

```
0 10 a namez 1 0
0 11 b namea 1 1
1 12 c nameb 1 1
2 13 d namec 0 1
3 14 e named 1 1
```

So my file will not always be the same number of lines, but always the same number of variables per line.

I currently have this, to firstly get the length of the file and then change the amount of rows within the array:

```
int FileLength()
{

    int linecount = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream WorkingFile("file.txt");
    while(getline(WorkingFile, line))
    {
        ++linecount;
    }
    return linecount;
}
int main()
{
    string FileTable [FileLength()][6];
}
```

Firstly I don't know if the above code is correct or how I can add the values from my file into my `FileTable` array.

Once I have my `FileTable` array with all the file data in it, I then want to be able to use this in other functions.

I've been able to do:

```
if(FileTable[2][0] = 1)
{
    cout << "The third name is: " << FileTable[2][3] << endl;
}
```

I understand my code may not make sense here but I hope it demonstrates what I'm attempting to do.

I have to do this for a larger text file and all the 6 variables per line relate to be input to a function.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays (`string FileTable [FileLength()][6];`) are not standard C++. If your compiler supports this isn't extension and should not be considered portable. Shouldn't even consider using it but hey unicorns or something.

Comment: Is there any other way of been able to store the information from the text file without having a fixed amount of data to store? Maybe creating multiple array's within a loop? I'm not saying my code is correct but giving said example to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve but have little idea of how to go about it.

Comment: Stuff your data in a struct and store it in a [`std::vector<TYPE>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Much simpler. If you really need multidimensional array use `std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>>`.

Comment: Oh alright, I've not worked with vectors before, I shall take a look into this, thanks :)

Comment: You might do well to consider a standard data format... there are loads to choose from (json, yaml, xml if you're desparate), and many libraries available to process them. You'll get the benefit of robust, tested, working code and a far more versatile data format than the one you've proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold each line in its own object, this is much clearer:

```
struct Entry
{
    std::array<std::string, 6> items;  // or a vector
};
```

In main:

```
std::vector<Entry> file_table( FileLength() );
```

Note that it is a waste of time to read the whole file first in order to find the number of entries. You could just start with an empty vector, and push in each entry as you read it.

Your access code:

```
if( file_table.size() > 2 && file_table[2].items[0] == "1" )
{
    cout << "The third name is: " << FileTable[2].items[2] << endl;
}
```

I would actually recommend giving the members of `Entry` names, instead of just having an array of 6 of them. That would make your code more readable. (Unless you really need to iterate over them, in which case you can use an enum for the indices).

You could define an `operator[]` overload for `Entry` if you don't like the `.items` bit.

Answer (score 0):

since the number of lines is dynamic I suggest to use vector instead of array. you can push back your data to the vector line by line until you read eof.
also try to study about OOP a little , it would make your code more understandable.

take look at these:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eof-and-feof-in-c/